# Simple Angular Date filter throws a TypeError exception

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

First, I have to point out that the filter works, even though I get the exception. The exception is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
```

I register the filter to the module, and as far as I know, I can use that filter in any controller. The `ngRepeat` is in one controller, and the `h3` is in another. The `ngRepeat` usage works, without any exceptions, but the `h3` one throws the one above, even though it shows the date in the correct format.

**The filter**

```
var Filter = function() {
    return function(jsonDate) {
        return new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
    };
};
AppModule.filter("jsonToAngularDate", Filter);
```

**Usage**

```
{{ order.Date | jsonToAngularDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy' }}
```

The exact same usage is used in both places.

**UPDATE**

Turns out I get the error because I load the date asynchronously. How do I avoid getting the error? Should I grab the data in the `init` function?

Comment: What's the content of order.Date? There is where the problem probably is. Also, try providing an example in http://plunker.co

Comment: The filter works just fine. The reason why you are getting this error is because this field most likely allows null content in the database, so you are getting mixed content. You should handle these cases too before processing the data and assuming it is always going to be a string.

Comment: @Jodevan It's a simple table of orders that has order# and date. When you click the details button it takes you to the details page. On the details page, I get this error. Without any filters, I get this: /Date(1420066800000)/

Comment: @DavidMeza it can't be null because it does show the correct date, but throws an exception and I don't know why. Also it isn't a nullable field.

Comment: If you are getting your data async, the filter will fail when order.Date is undefined, until your promise is fulfilled and the scope updates.

Comment: That is the case :) how should I handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the filter to account for nulls.

```
var Filter = function() {
    return function(jsonDate) {
        return jsonDate ? new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6))) : '';
    };
};
AppModule.filter("jsonToAngularDate", Filter);
```